# meaning of a phrase in mathematic paragraph

Tags: calculus

Suppose $x(t) \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and denote $\dot{x} $ its derivative.

Let $F(x, \dot{x}, t)$ be a function. Suppose we can find an $x(t)$ so that the integral

$$ \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} F(x, \dot{x}, t) dt $$

is a minimum. Now, consider the vector $x(t) + \delta x$ where $\delta x$ is a small change. So that the following better be positive

$$ \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} F(x + \delta x, \dot{x} + \delta \dot{x}, t) d t -  \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} F(x, \dot{x}, t) dt $$

Expanding this in powers of variations $\delta x $ and its trivially, one trivially see that the leading terms are of the first order.

#### Question:

In the last sentence, when it says trivially, I dont know if it is really trivial this statement because I cant see it. When they say expand in terms of $\delta x$ and $\delta \dot{x}$ , does he mean that we have to expand with taylor series expansion? Also, leadings terms are of the first order, does he mean that the leading terms are linear? But, how can we expand such a function? I mean $F$ is a function of $2n +1$ variables.

Comment: Yes... expand $F(x + \delta x, ...)$ in a Taylor series.  After subtraction, the leading term is "trivially" linear (first-order).

Comment: but it is the regular taylor series? we have more than one variables that it what is causin confusion

Comment: Taylor series apply perfectly well to $n$-variable functions:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables

Comment: yes I see now, just working out the details is cumbersome for this problem